# How to reduce number of python code?

Tags: python, dictionary, coding-style, refactoring

How to reduce number of code when element does not already exist in dictionary? Otherwise assign it to the object.
Prove of python concept:

```
class MyClass:
    pass

key = "test python"
item = MyClass()
d = {}
if d.get(key) is None:
    d[key] = item
else:
    item = d[key]
print(item)
```

Is it possible to remove if else statement?

Comment: Well, what happens with your test cases when you *do* remove the `else`?  Do you get the same results for all cases?  Test at least when the key is, and is not, already in the dict.

Comment: Are you using `d.get(key) is None` as an attempt to test whether the dict has that key? If so, that should be `key in d`. `d.get(key) is None` doesn't distinguish between a not-present key and an explicit `None`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read python documentation -> **[setdefault](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault)**:

```
class MyClass:
    pass

key = 'test python'
item = MyClass()
d = {}
item = d.setdefault(key, item)
```

It`s more pythonic!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe see if using `defaultdict` (from collections) would help?

I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do, but I think this is the same behavior?

```
from collections import defaultdict

class MyClass:
    pass

key = "test python"
item = MyClass()
d = defaultdict()
d[key] = item
print(item)
```

Unrelated, with the above, I think

```
if not key in d:
```

or

```
if not d.get(key):
```

might be a little more pythonic?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [dict.setdefault](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) for this:

```
key = "test python"
item = MyClass()
d = {}
print(d.setdefault(key, item))
```

Answer (score 1):

Read up on [Documentation](http://Read%20up%20documentation:%20https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#dict) before you start asking questions...

You want to use this `setdefault(key[, default])`